# Bash line breaks

Tags: bash

I am using Git Bash to recursively find all of the file extensions in our legacy web site. When I pipe it to a file I would like to add line-breaks and a period in front of the file extension.

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" | grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$" | grep -o -E "[[:alpha:]]{1,12}" | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | sort -u
```

Comment: Please try to write your titles to not just describe the topic of a question, but to actually ask the question itself to the extent possible.

Comment: In this case here, it would be helpful to provide a sample of your current output, and your intended/expected output. Even better would be to replace the `find` command with an `echo` or `printf` so anyone can run the command to see the issue themselves even if they don't have the same filenames.

Comment: the posted pipeline looks redundant: post a testable input and expected output

Comment: Actually, this can be run in any directory and you will get output. How can I pipe this to a file and have the link-breaks in the file?

Comment: Agree that an `echo .....| grep` would have been easier to test with, but yes, I get output in a dir without subdirs. When I "took your code apart" (pipe by pipe), I found it converted `mp3` to `mp`. As to why you're not getting line breaks, its hard to understand, as your output (with `mp` in it) has line breaks and `awk {print}` will include a line break AND sort -u will add line breaks.  It should be easy to either add `"."` in your `awk print` or extend your reg-ex to capture the leading `.` as well. Good luck.

Comment: As to "How can I pipe this to a file" , redirect the pipeline into a file with `find ... | grep ... | sort -u > uniqFile` or `man tee` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways.
When you do not want to change your existing commands I am tempted to use

```
printf ".%s\n" $(find . -type f -name "*\.*" | grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$" |
  grep -o -E "[[:alpha:]]{1,12}" | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | sort -u ) # Wrong
```

This is incorrect. When a file extension has a space (like `example.with space`), it will be split into different lines.
Your command already outputs everyring into different lines, so you can just put a dot before each line with `| sed 's/^/./'` 
You can skip commands in the pipeline. You can let `awk` put a dot in front of a line with

```
find . -type f -name "*\.*" | grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$" | grep -o -E "[[:alpha:]]{1,12}" | awk '{print "." tolower($0)}' | sort -u
```

Or you can let `sed` ad the dot, with GNU sed also convert in lowercase.

find . -type f -name "*.*" | sed -r 's/.*.([^.]*)$/.\L\1/' | sort -u

In the last command I skipped the `grep` on 12 chars, I think it works different than you like:

```
echo test.qqqwwweeerrrtttyyyuuuiiioooppp | grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$" | grep -o -E "[[:alpha:]]{1,12}"
```

Adding a second line break for each line, can be done in different ways.
When you have the `awk` command, swith the `awk` and  `sort` and use

```
awk '{print "." tolower($0) "\n"}'
```

Or add newlines at the end of the pipeline: `sed 's/$/\n/'`.